# Build heatmap/attention map over an image from points coordinates with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, coordinates, heatmap, density-plot

I would like to build an heatmap from points coordinates overlapping an image (in grayscale). I have the x and y coordinates of my points. The idea is to easily see the attention/density, where points are concentrated (red region if there is an important number of points).

I think I can use OpenCV for this. The following function sounds interesting: `applyColorMap(src, result, cv::COLORMAP_JET);`. But I don't know how to link this map to the points and not to the image.

Does someone know how to build an heatmap from points coordinates please?

Thanks to @berak's code and using `COLORMAP_RAINBOW` instead of `COLORMAP_JET` here is what I obtain:[image]
This is close to the result I want exept that it seems too "discrete" and not "smooth"/"fuzzy" enough. I don't want points to appear (specially those which are "alone"), I want density zone to clearly show up like [here](http://www.markcregan.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/mouse-move-heat-map1.png).
As some of you said I think I "just" need to change the intensity of pixels around my ROI.

Does someone have more clues please?

Comment: similar to what berak suggests I think about something like that (since you ask about density of points): for each point, draw a small (size depends on the "region" size you are interested in) filled circle (or gaussian) and sum those circles in an empty image. after that, high density regions have high values.

Answer (score 4):

here's my idea, - apply a distance transform to visualize the point density:

```
// generate demo data, you will just set your pixels here:
RNG &ran(theRNG());
Mat img(300,300,CV_8U,Scalar(255)); // inverted b/w scheme
for ( int i=0; i<600; i++ )
{
    int x=ran.uniform(0,300);
    int y=ran.uniform(0,300);
    img.at<uchar>(y,x) = 0;
}

Mat draw;
distanceTransform(img,draw,CV_DIST_L2,5);

// back from float to uchar, needs a heuristic scale factor here (10 works nice for the demo)
draw.convertTo(draw,CV_8U,10);    
// cerr << draw(Rect(30,30,10,10)) << endl; // peek into the data, does it look good ?

applyColorMap(draw,draw, cv::COLORMAP_JET);

imshow("jetmap",draw);
waitKey();
```

[image: from ponts to jetmap]

Comment: Sounds interesting. But I would like to do the other way: in red when there is a lot of points no where no points as it seems to be with your code. I will have a look and let you know thank you.

Comment: yea, you're right. distance is actually the opposite of density, so the outcome is inverted.

Comment: Maybe using COLORMAP_RAINBOW instead of COLORMAP_JET will do the trick. By the way which include do you need to use DIST_L2 please?

Comment: opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp

Comment: Actually it's `CV_DIST_L2` not `DIST_L2`

Comment: aww, dear, on 3.0 here. CV_DIST_L2 in 2.4 branch. yea, beat me !

Comment: No problem ! I tried your code using COLORMAP_RAINBOW instead of COLORMAP_JET and that seems fine thank you ! I will try with that!

Comment: Actually this is close to what I need but not "smooth" enough and too "discrete". I don't want to see points in the heatmap but just color like [here](http://img.blogsolute.com/heatmap-.jpg). Any ideas?

Comment: you need the contrib repository to be added in your opencv setup

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to use a single-channel image (ideally with more BPP than the usual 8-bit images), initialize it to zero and then iterate over all the points. Then you would increment the pixel corresponding to each point, resulting in high values where many points fall, and low values where there is no point.

Optionally, if you want a rather "fuzzy" map (hard to find a correct term for that...), you could not only increment all pixels where there are points, but all pixels in a circle around the points.

Then, you can convert the map to grayscale image or to a colored one via `applyColorMap`.

Comment: Ok I think I see. I will try to "play" with the pixels then not the points as was my idea at the beginning.

Comment: Actually yes I am looking for something more "fuzzy"/"smooth" as I said in comments to @berak.